# Push box to top of page without overlapping other content

Tags: php, html, css

I am writing an error console which will run after the output of my HTML within my framework. Effectively the console will capture all PHP errors, notices and other application related notices. As the PHP function to generate the box will only run after output of the the page HTML, the error console would then be positioned at the bottom of the page.

I would like to be able to push the console to the top of the page before any other output. I understand I could use something like position: absolute, but this appears to then overlap other content I already have. As the console will never be a fixed height I also cannot use margins or padding to try push other content out.

Is there a way to achieve this without relying on Javascript to do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture all of your normal output with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), i.e., enclose it in `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`, then prepare your error console data, output that to the client and only then output the content that was captured by output buffering.

A most trivial example:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    echo 'Normal content';
    $NormalContent = ob_get_clean();

    echo 'Error console';

    echo $NormalContent;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to do it with jQuery library if it is an option for you.

This way will be very simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.console').insertBefore('.content')
});
```

It will work with any height and will not be fixed or overlapping any other layer.

[LIVING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SKkBw/)